# delayed_job locking up locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I recently installed delayed_job_active_record and went through the typical install steps for heroku and for some reason when I run locally I (and another dev on my team) keep getting an error where our web process locks up trying to update the locked_at.

```
15:22:35 web.1    | started with pid 672
15:22:35 worker.1 | started with pid 673
...
15:23:23 web.1    |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.0ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2013-05-28 22:22:48.419281', locked_by = 'host:Jons-MacBook-Pro.local pid:673' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-05-28 22:22:48.418576' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-05-28 18:22:48.418615') OR locked_by = 'host:Jons-MacBook-Pro.local pid:673') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

The PID being referenced is the worker PID, but I have a fresh db (did a db:drop db:create db:migrate to test) and there are no delayed jobs so there is no reason for the delayed_job to be locking anything.

So.. does anyone have advice on where I should start debugging something like this? I can't seem to find the source of it and would love some help in figuring out where to look.

Comment: To clarify a bit, the web process calls the last line about 6-7 times before finally freezing permanently.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, could you post an answer if you found the solution. That would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I honestly don't remember what I did to to debug this.. I really should have written it down and posted again here - sorry :(

Comment: hrm. I'm having the same issue. If I fix it I'll come back and comment here :)

Comment: Ok, in my brief research on this (my previous comment appears to be 7 minutes old) - this is _not_ a 'lock up' or a bug. it's just a slightly spammy log from the job worker. see here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/886